# Non-minimal coupling (Pauli Coupling) of gauge field with a non-relativistic scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, symmetry-breaking

I am wondering if it makes any sense to non-minimally (say, Pauli-like) couple an external gauge field with a *non-relativistic scalar* field:
\begin{equation}
p_\mu \rightarrow p_\mu - e A_\mu + \epsilon_{\mu \nu \rho}F^{\nu \rho} ,
\end{equation}

here $F^{\nu \rho}$ is the electromagnetic tensor, written for two spatial dimensions. Please note, I am not referring to gravitational gauge field. Of course, one can do the maths and calculate some observables in such a scenario, however, does there exist any experimental paradigm where such calculations can be verified. I'd presume, if such couplings can be realized then many important effects related to breaking of time-reversal symmetry can be realized without applying any magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, the Pauli interaction is not 'required' if one just invoke the gauge principle minimally. It is also nonrenormalizable by the way. There are mathematical arguments of why it should be forbidden, e.g. in [hep-th/0005191](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0005191). If that doesn't bother you, you can also try to check its phenomenological consequences, for example the anomalous magnetic dipole moment as in [hep-th/9903179](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903179) and then compare it with the muon/electron g-2 experiments.
Besides, there are studies on generating fractional spin in terms of Pauli interactions.